# How to get the PID of a running process without waiting for it to terminate?

Tags: python, linux, terminal

My task is to start the process and save its PID in my program. The problem is that after executing this command, my program hangs, because it is waiting for the completion of the script that is launched through popen. And I need to continue her work. It would be possible to execute popen in a separate thread, but I thought there were other ways to solve this problem. Moreover, there can be many such programs.

I tryed this:

```py
pid = os.popen(f'python3 {path} & echo $!')
```

Comment: I do not know if you _want_ specifically to get the pid __or__ you want your program not to hang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `os.popen`. Use `subprocess`.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python3', path])
```

With launching python processes, you might consider `multiprocessing`.